# google maps api v3: handle user click on map type control?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, controls, dom-events

I need to handle the case when a user clicks on a `mapTypeControl` differently than when it's set through `map.setMapTypeId()`. How do I listen for clicks on map type controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't listen for events on the default UI control set. But if you are strictly focused on differentiating between clicks on the `mapTypeControl` and `map.setMapTypeId()`, you could use the fact that you control the code that may call `setMapTypeId()` and add some state management code:

```
// First, add a new state var:
var typeIdChangedInCode = false;

// Then, anywhere in your code where you call setMapTypeId(), add this:
typeIdChangedInCode = true;
map.setMapTypeId( newTypeId ); 

// Finally, include state checking code in the map event listener:
google.maps.event.addListener( map, "maptypeid_changed", function( evnt ) {
    if ( typeIdChangedInCode ) {
        //handle the scenario in the non-click way, but REMEMBER TO:
        typeIdChangedInCode = false;
    }
    else {
        //handle the scenario in the map click way
    }
});
```

This should set you up to handle the two different occurrences in the way you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', function(e){
           alert(map.getMapTypeId());
   });
```

Comment: How do I tell if this is the result of a programmatic maptype change or the user clicking on the control? This appears to fire in both cases (which is why I was asking the question).